# PHP Detect phonegap / cordova application http request

Tags: php, cordova, http, request, phonegap

So I am building a phonegap based application and I'd like that application to get it's information from a source using a http request to this source. This source however, must only be able to deliver data to this specific source and no info to any other source what so ever.

I can surely add parameters to the request, however, these parameters can easily be found by decompiling the application file. Is there a possibility for the server to know that the source indeed is my specific application without having to hardcode any kind of key into the app that easily can be obtained?

This all is to ensure that only this app can use a service and somebody else can't make use of that api.

Answer (score 1):

You can't really secure your app with a login/secret embedded inside your app. But if you craft a token system that delivers an access token back to a user upon identification of that user. Bottom line, you need to start with a register/login screen.

I recommend [this lib](https://github.com/bshaffer/oauth2-server-php) for php, and the `Client Credentials` grant seems like it would be what you want, see [grant types](https://bshaffer.github.io/oauth2-server-php-docs/overview/grant-types/)